# Heroku MEAN App deployment

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, mean-stack

I spent hours trying to fix a MEAN App deployment issue in heroku.  The app builds fine but I get an error stating that it can't find the resource icon.ico in the server.  I have searched the issue here and there are others with the same issue but a clear solution was never provided.  Hopefully you may assist.

Below is the browser error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

Comment: submitted a ticket to heCurrently I see your app is crashing with the following:
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch This happens when you don't bind to the port specified by $PORT. This is likely due to the fact that you start script is ng serve which needs to compile everything and will serve on port 6081. You probably want to change you start script to node server.js or something similarroku and recieved the following response: